# Is there any reason to hang out if a confidant's bond will not get stronger?

Tags: persona-5

In Persona 5 I have been hanging out with all of my connections whenever I am told that I feel my bond is getting stronger with them. However many times when I talk to these people to see if they want to hang out it tells me that I do not feel like our bond will get stronger which leads to my question.

Is there any reason for me to hang out with my connections when it tells me that our bond will get stronger? Since this is Persona I do not want to waste a period of time and not get any progress with a confidants. So is there any sort of benefit of hanging out with my confidants when I am told my bond will not grow stronger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This increases your relationship with them by a set amount (I'm not sure what it is for this game).  Bringing along a Persona of the same Arcana will increase it further, as well. Each time you hang out with them will get you closer to their next Social Link rank.

It's worth noting that during the rank increase hangouts, picking the correct dialogue choices will increase your relationship further. The blue "music notes" represent boosts to your relationship. The more you get while hanging out with a Confidant will decrease the amount of time you'll need to spend with them until your Social Link increases another rank.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a reason - you're still gaining bond with that confidant. You just don't have enough to rank up yet.

You can avoid having to spend time like this via using a persona of the matching arcana while hanging out with the confidant and answering in a way that pleases them during events.

There are also non-hang out events that can lead to improved relations (e.g. studying together).

In the past, it's been impossible to completely avoid these non-rank ups. But with careful planning you can minimize the number of times you need to do them.